# CoreML Output labels NSCFString - Labels not showing correctly

Tags: ios, swift, machine-learning, computer-vision, coreml

I am working on an iOS app where I need to use a CoreML model to perform image classification.

I used Google Cloud Platform AutoML Vision to train the model. Google provides a CoreML version of the model and I downloaded it to use in my app.

I followed Google's tutorial and everything appeared to be going smoothly. However when it use time to start using the model and got very strange prediction. I got the confidence of the prediction and then I got a very strange string that I didn't know what it was.

```
<VNClassificationObservation: 0x600002091d40> A7DBD70C-541C-4112-84A4-C6B4ED2EB7E2 requestRevision=1 confidence=0.332127 "CICAgICAwPmveRIJQWdsYWlzX2lv"
```

The string I am referring to is `CICAgICAwPmveRIJQWdsYWlzX2lv`.

After some research and debugging I found out that this is a NSCFString.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395135-nsclassfromstring

Apparently this is part of the foundation API. Does anyone has any experience with this?

With the CoreML file also comes a dict.txt file with the correct labels. Do I have to convert this string to the labels? How do I do that.

This the code I have so far.

```
//
//  Classification.swift
//  Lepidoptera
//
//  Created by Tomás Mamede on 15/09/2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 Tomás Santiago. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Vision
import CoreML
import ImageIO

class Classification {
    
    private lazy var classificationRequest: VNCoreMLRequest = {
        do {
            let model = try VNCoreMLModel(for: AutoML().model)
            let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: { [weak self] request, error in
                if let classifications = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] {
                    print(classifications.first ?? "No classification!")
                }
            
            })
            
            request.imageCropAndScaleOption = .scaleFit
            return request
        }
        catch {
            fatalError("Error! Can't use Model.")
        }
    }()
    
    func classifyImage(receivedImage: UIImage) {
        
        let orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation(rawValue: UInt32(receivedImage.imageOrientation.rawValue))
        
        if let image = CIImage(image: receivedImage) {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                
                let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image, orientation: orientation!)
                do {
                    try handler.perform([self.classificationRequest])
                }
                catch {
                    fatalError("Error classifying image!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider `NSCFString` as a  `NSString`, it's just an internal class for it. Since it's a NSString, it should be bridgeable without issue to `String`.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. The problem is that I don't want that string. I want the correct label and that is not the label the model should return... :/

Answer (score 0):

The labels are stored in your mlmodel file. If you open the mlmodel in the Xcode 12 model viewer, it will display what those labels are.

My guess is that instead of actual labels, your **mlmodel file** contains "CICAgICAwPmveRIJQWdsYWlzX2lv" and so on.

It looks like Google's AutoML does not put the correct class labels into the Core ML model.

You can make a dictionary in the app that maps "CICAgICAwPmveRIJQWdsYWlzX2lv" and so on to the real labels.

Or you can replace these labels inside the mlmodel file by editing it using coremltools. (My e-book Core ML Survival Guide has a chapter on how to replace the labels in the model.)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply. Is the model viewer only available in Xcode 12?

Comment: It also exists in previous versions of Xcode, but they don't show the labels. That new feature was added in Xcode 12. You can also view the class labels with the free Netron tool. Or you can load the model into a Python script using the coremltools library and examine it that way.

Comment: At the moment my CoreML Model is receiving a UIImage but the Output is a MultiArray MultiArray (Float32). I trained it in Google AutoML Vision Tool to classify images, so I expected it to give me back a label. But it does not... I have searched a lot and I can figure out how to do it.

Initially I had a CoreML Model that received a MultiArray Float(1 * 224 * 224) and that returned a another MultiArray float. I converted it using CoreML tools and now it receives an Image. But I can't change the output.

I am really struggling and I need help. Could you help me further?

Comment: When I print the spec of the model I get this as the output:

output {
  name: "scores"
  type {
    multiArrayType {
      dataType: FLOAT32
    }
  }
}

I want to change this object to give me the confidence as well as the classification label.

I want to change the output type.

Comment: What you're telling me doesn't add up. You wouldn't get a VNClassificationObservation result if your model was not a classifier. Core ML models can be different types: classifier, regressor, or generic neural network. You only get VNClassificationObservation if the model is a classifier. But if your output is a MultiArray, the model is not a classifier. So the information you're giving now does not seem relevant to the question you were asking.